# bootstrap3 - a div comes over the middle of the previous one (.well)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The text of the second div comes over the middle of the first div. How would I prevent this?

- **1st div** (row 12) contains 4 columns (row 3 each one)
- **2nd div** contains a row 12 each one

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Solutions</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row col-md-12" style="margin-top: 30px; height: auto;">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center"  style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center " style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center " style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center " style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="height: 60px; background-color: #3399cc;">
                <h2 style="color: white; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 60px;">THE TEXT THAT COMES OVER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't make a row div to hold your 1st div, try in that way.

Comment: I gess I did (the first div in the body : <div class="row col-md-12" style="margin-top: 30px; height: auto;">, anyway, eventhough I did it (add another row) but it doesn't work the 2nd div text still comes over the 1st div

Comment: Thank you Mr Forrence, I gess I find the solution :)
I have added the css height:auto for the first div and it work now
Thank you Mr Forrence for your prompt reply

Comment: The solution is to add the folowing css to the first div - **height: auto**;

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the folowing css to the first div - **height: auto**;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Solutions</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row col-md-12" style="margin-top: 30px; height: auto;">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center"  style="height: auto;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center " style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center " style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center " style="height: 250px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80" style="height: 80px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="margin-left : 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div>
                        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="height: 60px; background-color: #3399cc;">
                <h2 style="color: white; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 60px;">THE TEXT THAT COMES OVER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

     </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```